# How to make it so that Python will input everything first, then take initials after?

Tags: python

Basically the title. For some reason, this code prints initials after every input which is not what I want.

```
num_of_people = int(input("How many people will attend the meeting? "))
for i in range(num_of_people):
    name = input("What is the full name of participant " + str(i+1) + "?")
    split_name = name.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(split_name)):
         name_word = split_name[i]
    print (name_word[0])
```

I expected it to list all the initials of the people who attended the meeting.

Comment: `name` is overwritten with new input on each iteration of your first loop. You need create a list first, e.g. `names = []`, and then append to it `names.append(name)`.

Comment: And then you do not need to split. Just iterate over the list to get each element and get the first letter

Comment: the print function is in the main for loop, so it executes every loop

Answer (score 2):

It's printing every single time because you have it inside a single loop. For any program, you want to break it into a set of requirements, and then build up how you can accomplish those requirements. Based on your question, I'm guessing the requirements are:

1. Accept the number of participants from the user.
2. Accept the name of each participant from the user and store them.
3. Display the initials of all participants after all names have been entered.

You satisfy requirement 1 just fine. Requirement 2 is not satisfied. You accept each name and store it for a single loop, but as soon as you get to the next iteration, the name is overwritten. You should have a list that holds each name. For requirement 3, if you want the initials to be displayed after all names have been entered, you need to write that loop last. I'll try to use extra-descriptive variables.

```py
num_of_people = int(input("How many people will attend the meeting? "))
name_list = [] # This will be the list we store each name in.
for i in range(num_of_people):
    name = input(f"What is the full name of participant {i+1}? ")
    # We can use literal f-strings to format strings easier.
    name_list.append(name) # We add the name to our name list
    # This next line is so you can see what's happening. Take it out after.
    print(f"Name list is currently: {name_list}")

# We're done building the name list now. We want to print the initials
print("---Initials---")
for cur_name in name_list: # cur_name is the current name
    split_name = cur_name.split(" ")
    # split_name is now a list of each 'word' from the current name
    # If we want to take the initials only, we need to grab the first
    # element of each word in this list.
    for sub_name in split_name:
        # Now ask yourself how you want it to be formatted?
        # A common way would be with dots between each initial
        initial = sub_name[0]
        print(f"{initial}.", end = "")
        # We add end = "" so that no new-line is printed
    # After we print all the initials for the current name, add a newline.
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
How many people will attend the meeting? 4
What is the full name of participant 1? Pam Beezly Halpert
Name list is currently: ['Pam Beezly Halpert']
What is the full name of participant 2? Michael Scott
Name list is currently: ['Pam Beezly Halpert', 'Michael Scott']
What is the full name of participant 3? Dwight Schrute
Name list is currently: ['Pam Beezly Halpert', 'Michael Scott', 'Dwight Schrute']
What is the full name of participant 4? Holly Flax
Name list is currently: ['Pam Beezly Halpert', 'Michael Scott', 'Dwight Schrute', 'Holly Flax']
---Initials---
P.B.H.
M.S.
D.S.
H.F.
```

I recommend you take some time and look at tutorials online. There are some great ones at the official site: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Plus 1 for breaking it down into requirements.  So important.  Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way this can be done, using only two loops and the following techniques:

- The `join()` string function
- [List comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3)
- [String format function](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3)
- Proper case names
- Upper case initials

These are very useful tools to keep in your pocket.  :-)

```
# User prompt
num_of_people = int(input("How many people will attend the meeting? "))

# Initialise
initials = []
names = []
names_split = []

# Prompt user for each name.  Use proper case for each name, regardless of input.
for i in range(1, num_of_people+1):
    full_name = input("What is the full name of participant {}? ".format(i)).title()
    names.append(full_name)
    names_split.append(full_name.split())    

# Loop through names and build list of upper case initials.
for name in names_split:
    initials.append(''.join([i[0].upper() for i in name]))

# Print results.
print('\nNumber of participants:', num_of_people)
print('\nParticipant names:\n', names)
print('\nParticipant initials:\n', initials)
```

The output:

```
How many people will attend the meeting? 6
What is the full name of participant 1? One two THREE Four
What is the full name of participant 2? Sheldon Cooper
What is the full name of participant 3? Leonard hofstadter
What is the full name of participant 4? penny
What is the full name of participant 5? HOWARD woloWITZ
What is the full name of participant 6? raj koothrappali

Number of participants: 6

Participant names:
 ['One Two Three Four', 'Sheldon Cooper', 'Leonard Hofstadter', 'Penny', 'Howard Wolowitz', 'Raj Koothrappali']

Participant initials:
 ['OTTF', 'SC', 'LH', 'P', 'HW', 'RK']
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So we can try something like this:

```
num_of_people = int(input("How many people will attend the meeting? "))
for i in range(num_of_people):
    name = input("What is the full name of participant " + str(i+1) + "?")
    ## This loop stuff is not needed...
    ## split_name = name.split(" ")
    ## for i in range(len(split_name)):
    ##     name_word = split_name[i]
    print (name[0])
```

The bug in your code is pointed out in comments, so please have a lot at that :)

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but this does not meet the OP's requirements.  This only prints the first initial and does not store the initials in a list, as requested.  "I expected it to list all the initials of the people who attended the meeting."

Comment: Oops ! I didn't knew that. And by 'initials' OP meant the first letter of each name?? Bruh, in India (or at least in South India) by initials we mean the first letter before our name and it is our parent's name's first letter. Like my name is J Arun Mani and my initial is J because my father's name in Jeyaraman.... Sorry guys...